# Cordova app eating local storage space

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I am developing a cordova app which has a News section. I am fetching the news from server in JSON. Each news has about 10 images. When I am viewing the news in app it is taking space in the localstorage. It seems all the images are automatically downloading to the local storage. Is there any way not to download the images to the local storage? I need the user to only view the image from network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant stop from downloading but you can delete automatically when app is closed with `deleteLocalStorage` keyword, check the below link about localStorage https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html

Comment: Hi Naveen, I have some data that I do not want to delete from local storage. How can I delete only the downloaded images?

Comment: localStorage.removeItem("your downloaded file"); with this you can delete particular data,   localStorage.clear(); it removes all data from localStorage

Comment: I removed all the localstorage data by localStorage.clear method. But still in the App Info It is showing Data (10 MB). Is it application cache or where the images has been saved?

Comment: Application cache, If you clear that it does not affect your application data. You can clear that

Comment: I found the folder in which the images are saving. It is under `/data/<package_name>/app_webview` folder. I programmatically deleted the data when it reached 10MB and it works!